# How do you create a TileMap with Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I'm struggling to create a TileMap using Cocos2d. Regardless of what I try, I get the runtime error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30000008), which I understand to be a memory issue.

I've run the default cocos2d project, and it works. Then I add the following line in my init function:

```
CCTMXTiledMap* tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"TileMap.tmx"];
```

And my program breaks. As far as I can tell, this should be working. I'm using cocos2d 2.0, which is the latest stable version. I'm using XCode, and tried with both the 5.0 and 6.0 IPhone simulators.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Hmmm... So I installed Kobold2D, and used that instead of Cocos2D, and it seems to be working fine. I guess Cocos2D doesn't support this? This question isn't a blocker for me anymore, but if someone wants to shed some light, that would still be informative :)

Comment: how big is your tilemap, and how many tile layers does it have? Cocos2d's limit is 16,384 tiles.

Comment: It was a really simple map - 20x20, with a single layer.